# Returning something from a function that has a callback function

Tags: jquery

Nothing is being return from my function because it is asynchronous. How do I return the viallages?

```
function getVillages() {
    var self = this;
    this.a = [];
    VCare.VCareWebService.getFacilitiesForUser({cache:false,
        callback:function(xml) { // invoke the service
            // use jQuery to extract information we are interested in
            console.log(xml);
            var village = xml.getElementsByTagName("VCVillage");
            for (i=0;i<village.length;i++) { 
                self.a.push(village[i].getElementsByTagName("description")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue); // Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'push' of undefined 
                console.log(village[i].getElementsByTagName("description")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
            }

        }
   });
    console.log(self.a);
    //return(allVillages);
}
```

New attempt at making a village object and giving it an allVillages attribute and updating it:

```
function Villages() {
    this.allVillages = [];
}

function getVillages(village1) {
    VCare.VCareWebService.getFacilitiesForUser({cache:false,
        callback:function(xml, village1) { // invoke the service
            // use jQuery to extract information we are interested in
            console.log(xml);
            var village = xml.getElementsByTagName("VCVillage");
            for (i=0;i<village.length;i++) { 
                village1.allVillages.push(village[i].getElementsByTagName("description")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
                console.log(village[i].getElementsByTagName("description")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
            }
            if(typeof callback === "function") callback(xml);
        }
   });
    //return(allVillages);
}
```

function addVillages() {

```
village = new Villages();
console.log(village); //Villages {allVillages: Array[0]}

getVillages(village);
console.log(village.allVillages); //[]
for (i=0; i < data; i++) {
    console.log(data[i]);
    console.log(data[i][1]);
}
```

}

I get `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'push' of undefined` as village1 seems to be undefined. But I do pass it a correct Villages object

Comment: Your array is console logging before the function is completed is why.

Comment: Move your console logging within the callback function.

Comment: @MelanciaUK I need to return the array from the getVillages function. I don't think it gets returned when it is returning form within the callback function.

Comment: The point is, is this service running asynchronously? Like using AJAX to get the data? If so, you need to return what do you want after the callback has finished.

Comment: When your code step into the console logging, the callback can be still working.

Comment: @MelanciaUK yes. Thanks. How do I do that? Because shifting the return up seems to not return anything

Comment: You're logging something to the console within the _for loop_. If there's data coming, you can just return your array after the loop ends.

Comment: @MelanciaUK That returns nothing. Well, it returns the array, but it goes to nowhere, nothing can grab it.

Comment: I see... I got your point. You can pass this array to another function just to return it then.

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20047163/how-to-get-return-value-in-a-function-with-inside-ajax-call-jquery

Comment: @MelanciaUK Thanks. I'm not really sure how to call it with mine as my callback is different syntax

Comment: Have you tried something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/Lt44hy4u/1/

Comment: @MelanciaUK Thanks. Is that calling the VCare method twice? It alerts saying too busy to perform method, It does that when it gets called too many times.

Comment: Hard to say. I can't test it properly from here. Add some console logging points there.

Comment: It's a similar concept, but calling some other service (the one I can use in a jsFiddle): http://jsfiddle.net/Lt44hy4u/4/

Comment: @MelanciaUK Thank you I got your one working.

Comment: That's great. You can post the solution as your own answer and accept it then.

Answer (score 0):

Technique is found at this page [How to get return value in a function with inside Ajax call - JQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20047163/how-to-get-return-value-in-a-function-with-inside-ajax-call-jquery)

This is the working code:

```
function getVillages(callback) {
         var data = [];
        VCare.VCareWebService.getFacilitiesForUser({cache:false,
            callback:function(xml) { // invoke the service
                // use jQuery to extract information we are interested in
                console.log(xml);
                var village = xml.getElementsByTagName("VCVillage");

                for (i=0; i<village.length; i++) {
                    data.push(village[i].getElementsByTagName("description")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
                }

                if (typeof callback === "function") callback(data);            
            }
       });
    }

function addVillages() {
    var data = getVillages(function(data){
        for (i=0; i < data.length; i++) {
            //do whatever you want with the data
        }
    });
}
```